# Deleting specifc Prefetch file in C++

Tags: c++

Can you delete your own exe pf file? Without clearing your prefetch folder?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't (though I've never tried). Windows doesn't let you delete files that are in use, and the prefetch file is very obviously in use when your program is launched. Though you can probably schedule a MoveFile to no destination, assuming you have write permission to the prefetch folder (which equals a delete, only later).

Answer (score 0):

Straightforwardly, when a process is using a file, you can't:

- Replace it
- Modify it
- Delete it

Either you need somehow to kill the application before deleting it programmatically which is using the file or schedule the file to delete later.

Comment: This only applies to Windows, but since this is about exe, that's probably fine

Answer (score 0):

I did a self destruct thing that exit the app then delete the file.
I used this code

```
std::string command = "del /Q ";
            std::string path = "C:\\Windows\\Prefetch\\AUDIOZ.*.pf";
            system(command.append(path).c_str());
```